# Dreamweaver templates transforming coldfusion <cfinclude> paths from relative to absolute

Tags: html, coldfusion, dreamweaver

I am pretty new to both Dreamweaver and Coldfusion, and I am having a terrible time figuring out this issue.  I am sure the fix is very simple.

When I create a new page from an existing template in dreamweaver, any of my  tags get their paths resolved by Dreamweaver from relative to absolute, with respect to my local copy of the site, not the remote site.

For instance,

In my template I have something like

```
<cfinclude template="../../stuff.cfm"\>
```

But when I create a new page from that template I get

```
<cfinclude template="file:///C|/Users/Me/Documents/MySite/stuff.cfm">
```

Which is obviously incorrect.
How can I change it so that when creating a page from a template in Dreamweaver, it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it uses file:///C: until you save the new document.
Then it changes it to a relative location.

Comment: This ends up being more or less correct.  It turns out that Dreamweaver will use an absolute path until I reapply or update the template through normal use, then it will change absolute paths to relative paths.  It seems like very strange behavior to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<cfinclude template="#ExpandPath("../../stuff.cfm")#"/>
```

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c67.html

Comment: Physical paths like this will not work according to the Adobe CF docs.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ea7.html

Answer (score 1):

The "in code" answer is the right way to approach this, but for general path preferences, you can set that in Dreamweaver too:
[Set the relative path of new links](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c3ea.html#WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c35a)

Comment: You can also do <cfinclude template="/path/from/root/to/file.cfm" />, avoiding expandPath().

Answer (score 0):

Once the document is saved Dreamweaver will updated the links to Relative Paths to the document.